# Vaadin Adding Javascript to Custom Layout

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I've read the other posts regarding this topic already.
I just want to clarify, is there really no way in vaadin to:

- Create a custom layout html file, like custom.html;
- Import a java script file to it, then...;
- Call the js functions from within the html file, like one would normally?

Currently I have home.html in my Vaadin\themes(project)\layouts and a javascript library in Vaadin\js\custom.js.
In my Panel class i have annotation `@JavaScript({"vaadin://js/custom.js"})`, and in my html i tried `<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>`.

I have in the html file some hyperlinks, that need to call the js functions when clicked.

Any info if this is possible, would be most helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to call it directly from your html layout. Notice that your custom html file its only a layout thus Vaadin generates his own html using your layout AND server side code. Thats why your `<script>` annotation is not only redundant - it is simply useless.

However its still possible to call JavaScript using Vaadin. Using listeners you can call client-side code from the server:

```
ok.addClickListener(new ClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("itsHot()");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok
I had seen an example of using JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(""), but was hoping there was a way to create the html rather than have it generated.

But thanks for the info, it makes sense now.

Comment: Note that if you are using @PreserveOnRefresh annotation in your UI class, then these JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(..) commands might not be executed on refresh. In the case of a click listener executing it it shouldn't be a problem though.