# Different background color depending on URL

Tags: css

I'd like to emphasize where a web application is loaded from: the local development environment vs a test or production environment.
To keep things simple, the mechanism should work just on CSS. But so far my CSS is a static file.

Is it possible to write a CSS that evaluates on the browser what background color to use, maybe based on the URL it was loaded from (localhost vs other hosts)?

Somehow I am hoping to get a solution based on [CSS Conditional Rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-conditional-5/#when-rule).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using CSS, however you can do this using JavaScript. Checking if the current URL that is visited contains a certain string. Then changing style, you can also of course add a class within the if statement.

If you were to run this snippet in the answer it is blue, if you run this snippet on your localhost it will be red.

```js
if (window.location.href.indexOf("stackoverflow") > -1) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
} else {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

The following screenshots will show how it effectively changes the background color based on the URL entered in the browser.

Without localhost in the name;
[image]

With localhost in the name;
[image]

To ignore everything that comes after the hostname and only take a look at the hostname and port you can use `location.host` seen in the following snippet.

```js
if (window.location.host.indexOf("localhost") > -1) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
} else {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

Comment: ignore the array, that is part of a test I am currently experiencing with

Comment: Well, I could try to match ` ://localhost` so the problem does not really occur. But
it moves the task to adding JavaScript to my UI framework. I will try to look into that then.

Comment: Alright glad I could help.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri just out of curiosity, what UI framework are you using? :)

Comment: For _reasons_ I am still on Vaadin 8

Comment: @FUZIION Yes, the answer is much better with screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is the correct one to my question, I found a solution that I want to share with others and possibly my future self.

Since in Vaadin 8 it is not possible to directly add JavaScript into the generated HTML output (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307205/vaadin-adding-javascript-to-custom-layout) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883069/vaadin-8-how-to-include-a-javascript-file-to-returned-web-page-and-execute-it)) it was easier for me to change the application slightly.

So in the application I added code like this. I am aware it does not check if the request was going to localhost - yet it checks that the client is on the same machine as the server, which essentially means the same.

```
public class App extends UI implements View {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        if ("127.0.0.1".equals(request.getRemoteAddr()) || "localhost".equals(request.getRemoteAddr())) {
            this.addStyleName("dev-environment");
        }
    }
}
```

Now as there is a new CSS class name in use, a simple tweak on the CSS did the trick:

```
// emphasize we are on localhost. The application sets the class name 'dev-environment' in this case
.dev-environment {
    background-color: #EEF0FF;
}
```